# how to race multiple zio effects and get first 2 that completes

Tags: scala, zio

`zio` has method `race` which returns the first winner, and interrupts all "losers".

How to get the first two or `n`  "winners" that finishes first, and interrupts all others?

The function signature looks like below, where `n` is the number of "winners", (not the max parallelism).  The output list has size `n`.

```
final def raceN[R, E, A](n: Int)(as: Iterable[ZIO[R, E, A]]): ZIO[R, Nothing, List[Either[E,A]]]
```

One use case i can think of is load the same data from different source in parallel, only get the first 2 that returns first, and compare their content to make sure they are the same. If different, fail.

Comment: I am not sure about **ZIO** terms, but in **CE3** you could do something like this: create a `Deferred[List[Either[E,A]]` , create also a `Ref[List[Either[E,A]]`, do a `parTraverse` on the input list, after each operation finishes you then do an `updateAndGet` on the `Ref` to prepend the result of the computation, you then check if the size is `n` _(or you could keep track of it on the `Ref` to avoid the cost of calling size)_. When that happens you complete the `Deferred`. Finally, you race the whole computation with the `Deferred.get`, meaning that once it is completed it will cancel them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Structured Concurrency primitives](https://zio.dev/reference/sync/countdownlatch/) that ZIO offers to build this, but keep in mind that you need to think of cases like "long running effects that do not complete within reasonable time" (hint: may be you need a timeout).

Here is a short implementation of the `raceN`

```scala
object MyApp extends ZIOAppDefault:

  final def raceN[R, E, A](n: Int)(as: Iterable[ZIO[R, E, A]]): ZIO[R, Nothing, List[Either[E, A]]] =
    for {
      results    <- Ref.make(List.empty[Either[E, A]])
      latch      <- CountdownLatch.make(n)
      fibers     <- ZIO.collectAll {
                      as.map { (eff: ZIO[R, E, A]) =>
                        (eff
                          .either
                          .flatMap(effRes => results.update(effRes :: _))
                          *> latch.countDown).fork
                      }
                    }
      _          <- latch.await
      _          <- ZIO.foreachDiscard(fibers)(_.interrupt)
      raceResult <- results.get
    } yield raceResult

  override val run: UIO[ExitCode] =
    val effects = (1 to 5).map(n => ZIO.sleep(n.seconds).as(n).flatMap(n => ZIO.cond(n % 2 == 1, n, s"error: $n")))
    raceN(2)(effects).flatMap(res => Console.printLine(res.toString).orDie) *> ZIO.succeed(ExitCode.success)
```